# How to speed up a while loop with many list filtering procedures each of 200 turtles runs on 2600 patches

Tags: performance, optimization, netlogo, behavior

I am working in a decision-making *ABM*, my turtles must identify the best land use change strategy based on the characteristics and availability of patches suitable to make the best decisions. However the code I have takes a lot of time to process the decision of the agent.

**this is a list of potential land use changes :**

```
   set landuselist [
    ;; in the list  
    ;;    +------------------------ landusechange
    ;;    |     +------------------ cost
    ;;    |     |    +------------- expectedprofit
    ;;    |     |    |  +---------- maize
    ;;    |     |    |  |    +----- expectedprofit(formodification)
    ;;    |     |    |  |    |
    [ "MEA1"  200  450  6  450 ] ;; maintenance of mechanized agriculture in patches with high suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA1"   50  350  3  350 ] ;; maintenance of traditional agriculture to traditional agriculture in patches with high suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "CAT1"  100  350  0  350 ] ;; maintenance of cattle ranching in any suitability except for null
    [ "AGF1"   50  600  1  600 ] ;; Maintenance of agroforestry with an age over or equal to 6 year on suitability over null for agroforestry
    [ "MEA2"  200  450  6  450 ] ;;  conversion of forest to mechanized agriculture in patches with high suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA2"  100  300  3  300 ] ;;  conversion of forest to traditional agriculture in patches with high suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "CAT2"  600  300  0  300 ] ;;      change from forest to cattle ranching in any patch with suitability over null suitability
    [ "AGF2"   50   50  1   50 ] ;; Maintenance of agroforestry with an age below 6 year on suitability over null for agroforestry
    [ "MEA3"  200  450  6  450 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different than forest and mechanized agriculture into mechanized agriculture in patches with high suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA3"   50  200  3  200 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different to forest or traditional agriculture to traditional agriculture in patches with high suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "CAT3"  600  300  0  300 ] ;;      change of land uses diferent to forest and cattle ranching to cattle ranching in any level of suitability
    [ "AGF3"  350   50  1   50 ] ;;      change from land uses different from forest and agroforestry  to agroforestry in any suitability level exepct for null for agroforestry
    [ "MEA4"  250  300  5  300 ] ;; maintenance of mechanized agriculture in patches with medium suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA4"   50  200  2  200 ] ;; maintenance of traditional agriculture to traditional agriculture in patches with medium suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "MEA5"  250  300  5  300 ] ;;  conversion of forest to mechanized agriculture in patches with medium suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA5"  100  200  2  200 ] ;;  conversion of forest to traditional agriculture in patches with medium suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "MEA6"  250  300  5  300 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different than forest and mechanized agriculture into mechanized agriculture in patches with medium suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA6"   50  150  2  150 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different to forest or traditional agriculture to traditional agriculture in patches with medium suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "MEA7"  250  250  4  250 ] ;; maintenance of mechanized agriculture in patches with low suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA7"   50  150  1  150 ] ;; maintenance of traditional agriculture on patches with traditional agriculture in patches with low suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "MEA8"  250  250  4  250 ] ;;  conversion of forest to mechanized agriculture in patches with low suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA8"  100  100  1  100 ] ;;  conversion of forest to traditional agriculture in patches with low suitability for traditional agriculture
    [ "MEA9"  250  250  4  250 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different than forest and mechanized agriculture into mechanized agriculture in patches with low suitability for mechanized agriculture
    [ "TRA9"   50  100  1  100 ] ;;  conversion of land uses different to forest or traditional agriculture to traditional agriculture in patches with low suitability for traditional agriculture
    ]
```

**this is my while loop :**

```
to decideforprofit            ;;;; procedure to create the decision model based.
                              ;;;;           It is a secondary process after maize self-consumption
set ownedpatcheslist []                   ;; used to create a list of patches owned by each agent
while [investablemoney >= 50] [           ;; defined as the smallest cost to do a land use change
    create-patch-types                    ;; create a list of available patches in its respective procedure to have only the available patches and their potential benefit in land use change
    set alternatives filter [parches -> member? (item 0 parches) patch-types] landuselist ;;; to work with a list for each turtle that we can modify, it filters the global list based on the lo
create-patch-types list
     let landuselist1 filter [lista -> item 1 lista <= investablemoney] alternatives;;; filter based on the budget of each turtle 
     let landuselist2 sort-with [ l -> item 2 l ] landuselist1 ;;; sort the alternatives of each turtle to find the most profitable one

ifelse empty? landuselist2 [ ;;; when there are not more patches then to continue the procedure as normal for the next turtle
      ;handle the case where there are no suitable patches
      ;show "NO AVAILABLE PATCHES"
]  [;;; if it is not empty then
  let highest-value first landuselist2 ;;; chose the most profitable land use change from the nested list 
  let value item 0 highest-value ;;; define the land use change "MEA1", "MEA2"... 
  set chosevalue value ;;; the turtle receive the order 
  let costs item 1 highest-value ;;; extract the cost of the decision from the list
  let income item 2  highest-value ;;; extract the income of the decision form the list
  set investablemoney (investablemoney - costs);; discount the cost to the variable investablemoney of turtles
  set savings (savings + income) ;;; add the income of the decision to the savings variable
  applydecisions;;;  procedure that execute the order in chosevalue
  ]

  if empty? landuselist2 or investablemoney < 50 [
      ;exit the while loop if there are no suitable alternatives or there is not enough investable money
      ;show "I am stopping#"
       stop
       ]
  ]
  ;;; end of the while
end
;;;decideforprofit()
```

**this is the procedure to create a list of available patches and land use change options :**

```
to create-patch-types   ;; this creates a list of patches
                        ;;      based on the patch suitability
                        ;;      current land use and ownership
  set patch-types []
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; choices for traditional agriculture

  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TRA") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA1" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999) and (TRAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA2" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA3" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TRA") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA4" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999)  and (TRAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA5" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)]  [set patch-types lput "TRA6" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TRA") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 1) and (inuse = 0)]  [set patch-types lput "TRA7" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999) and (TRAsuitability = 1) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TRA8" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (TRAsuitability = 1) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "TR9" patch-types]

  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; choices for mechanized agriculture

  if any? patches with [(land-use = "MEA")  and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA1" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999) and (MEAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA2" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["TRA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA3" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "MEA")  and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA4" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999) and (MEAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA5" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["TRA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 2) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA6" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "MEA")  and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 3) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA7" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999)  and (MEAsuitability = 1) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA8" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["TRA" "CAT" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (MEAsuitability = 1) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "MEA9" patch-types]

  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; choices for cattle ranching

  if any? patches with [(land-use = "CAT") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (CATsuitability  > 0) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "CAT1" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "TFM") and (OwnerId = 999)   and (CATsuitability  > 0) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "CAT2" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "TRA" "AGF"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (CATsuitability  > 0) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "CAT3" patch-types]

  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; choices for agroforestry

  if any? patches with [(land-use = "AGF") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0) and (age >= 6)] and any? patches with [(land-use = "AGF") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0) and (age >= 6)]  [set patch-types lput "AGF1" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [(land-use = "AGF") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0) and (age < 6)]  and any? patches with [(land-use = "AGF") and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0) and (age < 6)] [set patch-types lput "AGF2" patch-types]
  if any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "CAT" "TRA"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0)] and any? patches with [member? land-use ["MEA" "CAT" "TRA"] or (land-use = "FAL" and age > 4) and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and (AGFsuitability > 0) and (inuse = 0)] [set patch-types lput "AGF3" patch-types]

end
;;;create-patch-types()
```

**There is another procedure that executes on each land use change option.

this is an example :**

```
to applydecisions
  if (chosevalue = "TRA1") [move-to one-of patches with [land-use = "TRA" and (OwnerId = [who] of myself) and TRAsuitability = 3 and inuse = 0]
    ask patch-here [set land-use "TRA" set OwnerId [who] of myself set breedowner [breed] of myself  set inuse 1 ]
                           set ownedpatcheslist lput patch-here ownedpatcheslist ]
  if (chosevalue = "TRA2") [move-to one-of patches with [land-use = "TFM" and OwnerId = 999 and TRAsuitability = 3 and inuse = 0]
                           ask patch-here [set land-use "TRA"  set OwnerId [who] of myself set breedowner [breed] of myself set age 1 set inuse 1]
                           set ownedpatcheslist lput patch-here ownedpatcheslist]
end
;;;applydecisions()
```

How to make my model faster? What I have identified is that it takes long time for each turtle to run the while procedure because they must build a different list every time in the loop and per tick.

I would like to identify the best way to make the `decisionforprofit` loop faster in order that my turtles consider the money they have and the available patches (not owned by other turtles or already owned by the same turtle) to make land use change: currently I have 200 turtles and 2600 patches varying in three levels of suitability for each land use type.

Comment: What dId you try to isolate the most expensive part? Did you try to measure the actual costs - the times ( distributions of times-to-run ) - that each of the critical-sections of this implementation of the *ABM*-based computing-strategy actually takes per-turtle per-tick? Whereas the AGRI-policy is static, rule-based, a smart redesign of (static and/or on-the-fly pre-computable) "data-storage" may help avoid the most expensive, repetitive ( 200 x per tick ) list-construction, list-scanning all over the NetLogo world of 2k6 patches -- there your implementation spends most of the expensive time

Comment: Any expression that queries all the patches is suspect

Comment: Rather than test owner id over and over, first create a set of the patches owned by that turtle, then ask that set the other tests.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the DRY principle of programming.

**Don't Repeat Yourself.**

If you can find repeating patterns in your code, you will find opportunities to reduce the number of instructions being executed.

Consider `owner-id = [who] of myself`

First, `[who] of myself` is run many, many times. We might consider storing that in a local variable, then use that in the queries. But, using WHO as an ID is *poor NetLogo style*. In this case, just assign `myself` to the owner-id when the turtle claims the patch.

```netlogo
ask patches with [ patch-selection-criteria ]
[ set owner-id myself ]
```

Next, the test 'owner-id = myself`

Again this test is run against all the patches many times. That's thousands of unnecessary tests! Let's store that part of the query in a local variable.

```netlogo
let my-patches patches with [ owner-id = myself ]
if any? my-patches with [ test1 ] [ action1 ]
if any? my-patches with [ test2 ] [ action2 ]
;; ... and so on
```

We have now removed thousands and thousands of tests. You likely will see significant performance improvement.

Other possible improvements:

- See if you can avoid testing `member?`.
- See if you can use numeric codes instead of strings.
- See if you can avoid rebuilding thing that don't change
- See if you can arrange your data so filtering isn't needed
- See if you can transform searches into look-ups

That's a start. Hopefully someone will add more to ideas.

I don't have time to expand on this suggestion right now, but you may consider using other turtles as objects to hold and query your land use properties.